# Migrating .NET 7 to .NET 8 - 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, does not have an implementation.'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

After migrating from .NET 7 to .NET 8, I get this run time error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTypeMapping' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, Version=7.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

I have tried the following steps:

1. Migrate the target from .NET 7 to .NET 8. When it is tested, the error is replicated.
2. Migrate all libraries such as EF, Abstraction, DI from .NET 7 to .NET 8 - when it is tested, the error is replicated too.

Any suggestions?

---

The complete run time error is:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTypeMapping' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, Version=7.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTypeMappingSource.FindMapping(TypeMappingInfo& mappingInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSource.<>c.<FindMappingWithConversion>b__3_0(ValueTuple`4 k, TypeMappingSource self)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(TypeMappingInfo mappingInfo, Type providerClrType, ValueConverter customConverter)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(TypeMappingInfo mappingInfo, IReadOnlyList`1 principals)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSource.FindMapping(MemberInfo member)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.MemberClassifier.IsCandidatePrimitiveProperty(MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionModel model, CoreTypeMapping& typeMapping)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.Process(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.ProcessEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAddedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelConfigurationBuilder.CreateModelBuilder(ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService(IInfrastructure`1 accessor, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_ProviderName()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseFacadeExtensions.IsInMemory(DatabaseFacade database) in /_/src/HealthChecks.UI/Extensions/DatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs:line 11
   at HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.UIInitializationHostedService.ShouldMigrateDatabaseAsync(HealthChecksDb context) in /_/src/HealthChecks.UI/Core/HostedService/UIInitializationHostedService.cs:line 107
   at HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.UIInitializationHostedService.InitializeDatabaseAsync(IServiceProvider sp) in /_/src/HealthChecks.UI/Core/HostedService/UIInitializationHostedService.cs:line 48
   at HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.UIInitializationHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/HealthChecks.UI/Core/HostedService/UIInitializationHostedService.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
```

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: Which migrations do you expect from `InMemory` provider? For sure they are not implemented, there is no backing SQL Server engine to run these scripts. If it worked before, probably they made right decision to remove this.

Comment: I am checking all in my solution because is not not a desired behavior to use InMemory cache for SQL proposes, I also was researching the issue and it seems that `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` 8.X must be manually added as part of the project, it is a weird but for now all is running with thousand of errors. Once all run, I will document it all in this thread, thanks your point of view helps me to find no common practices.

Comment: The dynamic load of assemblies for third-party DI resolver or mappers seems to be the root, it is only a hypothesis that is being checked by my local team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a transitive dependency to the older version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` and the package that has that dependency needs to be updated to use the latest version, or you can just explicitly install the latest version of the transitive package and hope it works.

In our case the dependency came from `AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` so I had to explicitly install the newest version of the InMemory package to fix the problem.

You can check the `project.assets.json` file to find out which package has the dependency to the old version of InMemory package.

Comment: Just I have resolved it , installing (manually) the package as you have explained.